# поиск простых чисел для дроби

Tags: c

Всем привет! Задали задание, цитирую: "Дано целое число а. Найти все такие простые числа p, чтобы дробь была сократима на p. Простым называется натуральное число N, не имеющее других делителей, кроме 1 и самого N". Код написал, но ничего не работает, сам ошибок не вижу, но думаю Вы сможете помочь мне найти их и предотвратить.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    int a, a2 = a * a, nmr = a2 * a2 + 12 * a2 - 5, dnmr = a2 * a + 11 * a;
    int gcd = GCD(abs(nmr), abs(dnmr));
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("%d / %d : %d : ", nmr, dnmr, gcd);
    if (gcd > 1)
        primes_u(gcd);
    else
        printf("\nNo prime dividers.\n");
}

int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    while (a > 0 && b > 0) if (a > b) a %= b; else b %= a;
    return a + b;
}

void primes_u(int n)
{
    int d = 3;
    if (~n & 1) {
        printf(" 2");
        do n >>= 1; while (~n & 1);
    }
    while (d <= n) {
        if (n % d == 0) {
            printf(" %d", d);
            do n /= d; while (n % d == 0);
        }
        d += 2;
    }
}
```

P.S. 1 блок - поиск числителя nmr и знаменателя dnmr.
2 блок - поиск НОД(abs(nmr),abs(dnmr)).
3 блок - если он >1, то раскладываю его на простые множители без учета кратности, который будет ответом, иначе искомого просто не будет.

Простите, забыл дробь указать:[image: ur]

Comment: Какая дробь? ??

Comment: Как вы вычисляете `a2` не зная значения `a`? Воспользуйтесь отладчиком чтобы проверить код, который вы написали.

Comment: Да и когда факторизуете, нет смысла проверять все до `n`, достаточно до корня из `n`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Интересно, откуда такие вопросы? Нечасто, но бывает. Перенос опыта работы в Excel? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код после небольших исправлений:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int GCD(int a, int b) {
    while (a > 0 && b > 0) if (a > b) a %= b;
        else b %= a;

    return a + b;
    }

void primes_u(unsigned int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        printf(" 2");

        while (n % 2 == 0) n /= 2;
        }

    for (unsigned int d = 3; d * d <= n; d += 2)
        if (n % d == 0) {
            printf(" %d", d);

            while (n % d == 0) n /= d;
            }

    if (n != 1) printf(" %d", n);

    puts("");
    }

int main() {
    int a;
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    int a2 = a * a, nmr = (a2 + 12) * a2 - 5, dnmr = (a2 + 11) * a;
    int gcd = GCD(abs(nmr), abs(dnmr));
    printf("%d / %d : %d : ", nmr, dnmr, gcd);

    if (gcd > 1)
        primes_u(gcd);
    else
        printf("\nNo prime dividers.\n");
    }
```