# перевод функций кода для чайников

Tags: c

Всем привет! Сам новичок в сфере Си, и многое пока не понимаю. Однажды дали задачу на поиск простых делителей для большой дроби, и сюда же обращался за помощью, где Вы мне и помогли, но при попытке понять саму суть каждой строчки мне дается очень тяжело. Не думаю, что обязательно скидывать сюда весь код, поэтому скину ту часть, которую я вовсе не понял:

```
void prost(unsigned int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        printf(" 2");

        while (n % 2 == 0) n /= 2;
    }

    for (unsigned int d = 3; d * d <= n; d += 2)
        if (n % d == 0) {
            printf(" %d", d);

            while (n % d == 0) n /= d;
        }

    if (n != 1) printf(" %d", n);

    puts("");
}
```

Как мне сказали эта функция нужна для "разложения на уникальные простые". Буду рад вашим объяснениям!

Comment: А чего тебе помогать? Полюсов ты не ставишь, спасибо на говоришь. Даже вопрос понятный задать не можешь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, вы все же примете сразу два моих ответа, этот и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1459115/228791, а то и в самом деле Эникейщик прав, нет стимула вам помогать.

```
void prost(unsigned int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {   // Четное?
        printf(" 2");   // Выводим 2 и

        while (n % 2 == 0) n /= 2; // доводим до нечетного
    }

    // Проверяем делимость только на нечетные числа
    // Нет смысла проверять делимость на что-то больше корня: при таком
    // делении остается что-то меньше корня, а его мы уже проверили.
    for (unsigned int d = 3; d * d <= n; d += 2)
        if (n % d == 0) {     // если делится
            printf(" %d", d); // выводим

            while (n % d == 0) n /= d; // и убираем этот делитель вообще
        }

    // Если после этого что-то осталось, то n - простое число. Выводим его.    
    if (n != 1) printf(" %d", n);

    puts("");
}
```

Comment: поверьте, если бы я знал, что плюсы можно ставить, они бы появились еще в вашем прошлом ответе. А так, да, с моей стороны, правда, неприлично не благодарить вас за ответ, поэтому прошу прощения и спасибо вам!